# How to update-refresh Fragment in ViewPager on Tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout (tab1, tab2, tab3) with a ViewPager. I want to input something in tab1, and depends on the input, tab2 and tab3 will show data accordingly.

It seems every time the app start, tab1 (fragment) and tab2 (fragment) are loaded with correct data. I'm using static variable to pass data from tab1 to tab2. However, after I change some data in tab1, tab2 doesn't update itself base on the data from tab1, it shows the old data. Here are my codes

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PagerAdapter adapter;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
```

in my onCreate method within an activity.

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Input"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Detail"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chart"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Here's my pageadapater class

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;
private InputFragment inputFragment;
private DetailFragment detailFragment;
private ChartFragment chartFragment;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return POSITION_NONE;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            inputFragment = new InputFragment();
            return inputFragment;
        case 1:
            detailFragment = new detailFragment();
            return detailFragment;
        case 2:
            chartFragment = new ChartFragment();
            return chartFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```